# Using Regex to wrap xml element value with cdata

Tags: regex, xml, search, replace

I have to edit a stored procedure that builds xml strings so that all the element values are wrapped in cdata.  Some of the values have already been wrapped in cdata so I need to ignore those.

I figured this is a good attempt to learn some regex

```
From: <element>~DATA_04</element> 
to:   <element><![CDATA[~DATA_04]]></element>
```

What are my options on how to do this?  I can do simple regex, this is way more advanced.

NOTE:  The `<element>` is generic for illustration purposes, in reality, it could be anything and is unknown.

Sample text:

```
    declare @sql   nvarchar(max) =
'    <data>
    <header></header>
    <docInfo>Blah</docInfo>
    <someelement>~DATA_04</someelement>
    <anotherelement><![CDATA[~DATA_05]]></anotherelement>
</data>
'
```

Using the sample xml, the regex would need to find someelement and add cdata to it like `<someelement><![CDATA[~DATA_04]]></someelement>` and leave the other elements alone.

Bear in mind, I did not write this horrible sql code, i just have to edit it.

Comment: Use following webpage : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

This is c#:

```
string text = Regex.Replace( inputString, @"<element>~(.+)</element>", "<element>![CDATA[~$1]]</element>" , RegexOptions.None );
```

The find is:

```
<element>~(.+)</element>
```

The replace is:

```
<element>![CDATA[~$1]]</element>
```

I'm assuming there is a ~ at the start of the inside of the element tag.

You will also want to watch out for whitespace if that is an issue...

You may want to add some

```
\s*
```

Any whitespace characters, zero or more matches

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  The above wont work because the tag is unknown.  The reason for using regex in this situation is the sproc I need to edit  has literally thousands of elements to edit and I will probably need to edit multiple files so something quick and repeatable is what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `(<[^>]+>)(\~data_([^<]+))(<[^>]+>)`

and replace for `\1<![CDATA[\2]]>\4`

this will give you: `<element><![CDATA[~DATA_04]]></element>`,
where element could be anything else. Check the [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/wY1wV9/3)

Good luck

Comment: Thats close but not quite what I need.  It needs to only select and change strings that have the ~data_## without the cdata

Comment: Please check again, corrected due to wrongly understood requirements :)